# How to access a "private member" of a separate instance of the same "class"?

Tags: lua

[Related question: how do implemented protected members when using the closure approach to OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753478/1802240). The problem is most likely the same, although the abstraction that I'm trying to implement is different.

---

I'm currently implementing a tree structure to represent a scene graph in lua. To do so, lua has several ways of abstracting the concept of classes, and I'm using this one:

```
new_item = function()
    local _self = {}
    local _parent = nil
    local _children = {}

    _self.add_child = function(child)
        -- add child to _children
        table.insert(_children, child) -- no problems here

        -- set child's _parent to _self
        child._parent = _self -- this doesn't work: "child._parent" doesn't even exist
    end

    return _self
end

a = new_item()

b = new_item()
a.add_child(b)
```

The object returned by `new_item` is a table with a single item called `add_child`, which is the function I defined. The local variables `_self`, `_parent` and `_children` are local to the scope of `new_item`, captured from each "method", and are effectively "private members" of the "class".

Now, to keep the tree consistent, I am creating this function `add_child`, which will add the passed parameter (which is expected to be another object created with `new_item`) to the list of children of this object, and set the child's parent to this object.

In C++, C# and Java, I have the notion of "private members", and I can access those of a different instance of the same class. In lua though, these local variables are local to the scope of `new_item`, so they're not part of the exported object, so I can't access them.

I would like to have a way to implement this abstraction of "accessing private members of a separate instance of the same class", or do something else, so the parent and children links are only modifiable with exported "methods" that can be proven correct.

I think that what I want to do is simply not possible in lua, short of [putting `_parent` inside of `_self` (therefore making it "public"), and asking pretty please for nobody else to touch it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753478/1802240), which is, if I'm not mistaken, how Python deals with this.

However, there might be a way of achieving this that I have not thought of, maybe using a different way to abstract the concept of "class". Does anybody know how to go about implementing the abstraction of "accessing private members of a separate instance of the same class" in lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function create_class()
   local class = {}

   -- when object is garbage-collected, its private data will be auto-removed
   local private_data_of_all_objects = setmetatable({}, {__mode = "k"})

   function class.create_new_object()
      local object = {}   
      local private = {}  -- private fields of this object
      private.children = {}
      private.parent = nil
      private_data_of_all_objects[object] = private

      function object.add_child(child)
         table.insert(private.children, child)
         private_data_of_all_objects[child].parent = object
      end

      return object
   end

   return class
end

cl = create_class()

a = cl.create_new_object()
b = cl.create_new_object()
a.add_child(b)
```

Comment: That is a great use case for `__mode`. Thank you very much.